# Create Equation Graphs in windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-8

I am developing an application in which I am taking an equations like y=x*sin(x) and I want to draw the graph of this equation, to do this, I am calculating 10 values of y for 10 values of x, by putting the values for x and then parsing the equation to get y values.
How am I going to create graph of this equation using the 10 points I calculated, what is the control am I going to use??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14610930/windows-phone-8-draw-single-pixel) question and answer. It's proposed to use WritableBitmap class (and a library WritableBitmapEx) to draw separate pixels. Then you could use it to draw your function graph and put it to the screen like ordinary image.

One note still: you need to calculate all the points of the graph, not just 10 of those as you mentioned, if you want to present the complete curve. There's no automagical filling of missing dots between your calculated ones.